# magento 2 : Special price not showing properly in simple product

Tags: magento2

I have created simple products with special price in magento 2. It shows perfect in product detail page http://prntscr.com/mq5ll2, But when product shown on list page it shows price in range http://prntscr.com/mq5kln I want to show them same like this http://prntscr.com/mq5q86

**My Backend :** 
Step1 : http://prntscr.com/mq5rb7 
Step2 : http://prntscr.com/mq5rh9

Please suggest me if anyone know the solution

Comment: Most likely this is your theme. May be there is theme option somewhere. To confirm you can enable default theme and check.